# How to insert data to firestore using javascript in web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following the documentation properly and even the video that explains how does it work but for how many times I tried and even copied the exact code in the documentation I can't insert data on firestore database. Can you please tell me why is this happening? 
Also, there's no problem in my database because I already configure it read and write.

Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>
    <section class="container-fluid bg">
        <section class="row justify-content-center">
            <section class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <form class="form-container">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="codeidtextfield">Code ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codeidtextfield" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Code ID's are provided by the Higher Ups. You must request first if you don't have one.</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwordfield">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordfield">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
<!-- Firebase CDN -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>

    //This config data are fine, I just removed it for the sake of privacy i guess.
    var config = {
        apiKey: 
        authDomain:
        databaseURL: 
        projectId: 
        storageBucket: 
        messagingSenderId:
        appId: 
        measurementId: 
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    const db = firebase.firestore(app);

    const docRef = db.collection("Admin").doc('CourierApplicationId').collection('CodeIDS');
    const codeidField = document.querySelector("#codeidtextfield");
    const passwordField = document.querySelector("#passwordfield");
    const submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit_btn");

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        const codeid = codeidField.value;
        const passworddata = passwordField.value;

        console.log("I am going to authenticate: "+codeid+" and "+passworddata+" to Firestore database.");

        docRef.add({
        codeID: codeid,
        password: passworddata
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Here is the sample log of the program when I tried to run it.

[image]

Comment: is any one of this console.log appearing `.then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });`?

Comment: No sir. the only appearing was the result of the console.log for ex. `I am going to authenticate: 5734764564 and renneil to Firestore database.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
    // Initialize Firebase
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    const db = firebase.firestore(app);
```

into this:

```
    // Initialize Firebase
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    const db = app.firestore();
```

Use the `firestore()` method to connect to firestore:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App.html

Comment: add console.log inside the click event and check if it is even entering the click event, add `console.log(passworddata);`

Comment: @Mr.Baks Since your button is of type submit (`type="submit"`) your form is submitted  before the Firebase `add()` method is triggered.

You need to specify the button type as `button`, (and not `submit`) as follows:

`<button type="button" id="....">....</button>`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thank you! This solves the issue on the button and the insertion of the data.

Comment: @Peter Haddad thank you also! because you solved the issue of the initialization of the firestore!